# Spaces not rendering in span tags

Tags: html

I have the following HTML:

```
<html>

    <body>
           hi   hi    
           <br>
           <span>          hi   hi   </span>

    </body>
</html>
```

My expectation is that there would be spaces before the `hi  hi` which correspond to the spaces before them in the span. However, The spaces are not being rendered in Chrome:

[image]

How come space characters are not rendering in my span?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The output is a HTML webpage, and in HTML multiple spaces are collapsed to a single space. Spaces at the begining and end of the tag aren't visible.

You could solve this with css:

```
.showSpaces{
  white-space: pre;
}
```

and set the class in the html

```
<span class="showSpaces">          hi   hi   </span>
```

### Full example

```css
.showSpaces{
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<html>

    <body class="showSpaces">
           hi   hi    
           <br>
           <span>          hi   hi   </span>

    </body>
</html>
```

Another option is to use the `<pre>` tag in HTML.

Comment: `in html multiple spaces are collapsed to one space`  - I don't think that is happening here. There are not spaces before or after my text. It looks like its being ignored completely.

Comment: Well it's also happening her ;) but the first and last space is indeed not visible

Answer (score 3):

Use the non-breaking space html entity: `&nbsp;`

Using CSS to move your text over is probably better practice in your example.

Answer (score 2):

> My expectation is that there would be spaces before the hi  hi which
>   correspond to the spaces before them in the span.

by default, only one whitespace is provided in between words even if you apply more spaces. one way to overcome the issue is to use non-breaking space **[`&nbsp;`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)**.

```
<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;hi   hi </span>
```

though this is **not** the purpose of **[`&nbsp;`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)**.

a more suitable option would be to use the **[`pre`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp)** tag.

snippet:

```html
<html>
    <body>
           hi   hi    
           <br>
           <span><pre>          </pre>hi   hi   </span>
    </body>
</html>
```